# Exchange Server 2010 - Resolving Calendar Attendant\Requests Failed

Tags: exchange-2010, performance-monitoring, calendar, performance-counters, exchange-server

On my Exchange mailbox server, I am receiving the alert:

```
MSExchange Calendar Attendant\Requests Failed
```

Or in Solarwinds Orion:

```
Requests Failed (Calendar Attendant) for Exchange 2010 Mailbox Role Counters (Advanced) on *servername*
```

All I know is this figure should be 0 at all times. Currently I am at 2, and this is the only alert on the Exchange servers. No where I can find how to resolve this.  How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: This is old, but the question is still relevant with new versions of Exchange Server. If anyone else experiences this, I'd ask the op if they have a value of '2' on the server's performance counters and/or if they only have a value of '2' in Orion. If only in Orion, it is likely a bug, per this Thwack post: https://thwack.solarwinds.com/thread/97997.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know for sure that this figure should be 0 at all times?

I would take a look at this technet article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff360647(v=exchg.140).aspx

It lists a variety of solutions on the bottom. Also note that this article specifies 100 as the warning threshold, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Technet has conflicting information:

Calendar Attendant Counters

The following table shows Calendar Attendant counters.

Counter  Description     Threshold
MSExchange Calendar Attendant\Requests Failed
Shows the total number of failures that occurred while the Calendar Attendant was processing events.
Should be 0 at all times.